# Fix Polyinstantiation of /tmp causing 'connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory'

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, namespace, tmp

In a multiseat desktop system with the `/tmp` directory [polyinstantiated](https://www.google.com/search?q=polyinstantiation%20tmp), the `/tmp/.X11-unix/` directory and `Xn` instances are still created under root's `/tmp` not a user's.

`ssh -Y`ing into or out of the box and trying to run X11 applications (via X-forwarding) generates `connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory`

Presumably this is because the session is created by a root or system user account that isn't being instantiated, so ends up in the traditional `/tmp` location.

Would there be any way around this or are they just not compatible?

The system currently uses `lightdm` as the login manager so the `Xorg` session is run by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround, not a full blown solution is to wrap `ssh` in a script that creates a relay.

`~/bin/ssh`:

```
# Do we have a display?
# Does our display relay exist?
if [ ! -z $DISPLAY ] && \
   [ ! -e "/tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAY#*:}*" ]
then
    # Create X11-unix dir if need be.
    mkdir -p /tmp/.X11-unix

    # Create reusable display relay
    socat \
     UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAY#*:},fork,reuseaddr \
     ABSTRACT-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAY#*:} \
     &>/dev/null &
fi

# Do the useful thing...
/usr/bin/ssh $@
```